# How to get DB2 LUW trial version for Windows or where to practice online?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

First I downloaded the VMware and Redhat 6.5 on my 64bit Windows machine, created virtual machine, set the network and host as needed. 
Downloaded the db2 LUW 11.1 AMD64 for Linux, winscp the product to the redhat, unzip and tar -vxf the product.
But when I am checking the ./db2_prereqchk its fails, conveying that certan packages are not there to install the product.

Where can I download a trial version for Windows? Is anyone aware of an emulator online or cloud offer where DB2 can be practiced?

Answer (score 1):

You can [download trial versions of DB2 LUW at the IBM website](http://www.ibm.com/analytics/us/en/technology/db2/db2-trials.html). For testing DB2 online I would recommend to check out [dashDB on IBM Bluemix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/dashdb/). There are also [Docker images available for DB2 Express-C](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2express-c/), the free edition of DB2. So overall plenty of options.

Comment: I will try downloading Express-C and see if I can get platform to practice instead of trying to download 90 days trail version. Is anyone ever tried to download Express-C and what are the installation steps?

Comment: There are several (free e-) books that are covering DB2 Express-C, it has been around for many years and has a big user base. Download and start the setup program, done. Express-C on docker is even simpler.

Comment: Please close as answered.